# How to check if submit finished POST method to database and then re-render in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am submitting a form to back-end and then re-render component to get a list of new items. Right now I am doing re-render in componentDidUpdate function:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.props.fetchListStart();
}
```

My submit form looks like:

```
<form
  onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.submit();
    this.props.close();
  }}
>
  <div className="row" style={{ textAlign: 'start' }}>
    Do you really want?
    <div className="col-md-12 buttonContainer">
      <ButtonA
        label="Submit"
        style={{ width: '50%' }}
        primary
        type="submit"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So the problem is, that sometimes componentDidUpdate fire faster, than my submit updates data in the database. How should I check if my submit is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your fetchListStart() to the callback of the update function.

E.g.:

    `axios.post('/user', {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        fetchListStart();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });`

Comment: I am using Redux-saga not axios, but still thank you for your hint. I made it work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you need to call the setState function of the parent component in the success callback of your method which posts to db. Then call fetchListStart as callback to setState.

for e.g.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    submit(){
      fetch("/data").then(response=>{
        this.setState({
          data:response
        },this.fetchListStart())
      })
    }

    render(){
      return <ChildComponent {...this.state}  submit={this.submit} />
    }

}
```

I am assuming that you need to get the list of data only after the view is rendered. The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.